# Is there a way to get all colors in a single text layer?

Tags: javascript, jsx, photoshop, photoshop-script

I would like to write a script for Photoshop CS2 in js, which colors sql keywords inside a TextLayer blue for example and the non keywords black.
I know that there is support for multiple colors in a single TextLayer in the gui but in the documentation for js it doesn't mention anything about multiple colors for an ArtLayer, also no mentions in the TextItem object documentation.
I changed the color of the first letter in the Textlayer and only it's color is returned.
Here is my code so far:

```js
// enable double clicking from the Macintosh Finder or the Windows Explorer
#target photoshop

// in case we double clicked the file
app.bringToFront();

var doc = app.activeDocument;
var layers = collectAllLayers(doc);

// save all layers
function collectAllLayers (doc){
    var allLayers = [];
    for (var m = 0; m < doc.layers.length; m++){
        var theLayer = doc.layers[m];
        if (theLayer.typename === "ArtLayer"){
            allLayers.push(theLayer);
        }else{
            collectAllLayers(theLayer, allLayers);
        }
    }
    return allLayers;
}

// only use textlayers that contain this string
const sqlMarkerText = "code:sql";

var textLayers = [];
// save all textlayers containing marker
for(var i = 0; i<layers.length; i++){
    var layer = layers[i];
    if(layer.kind == LayerKind.TEXT && layer.name.indexOf(sqlMarkerText) != -1)
        textLayers.push(layer);    
}
```

After that I use the following method to get the color:

```js
// display color for layer
for(var i = 0; i<textLayers.length; i++){
    var layer = layers[i];
    alert(layer.textItem.color.rgb.hexValue);
}
```

color only returns a SolidColor. As the image below shows, one TextLayer has multiple colors but it would only return RED. [image: only one TextLayer]But I would like to have a SolidColor list or another way to get the colors :)
Is there a way to get **all colors from a single text layer**?

Comment: You won't be able to do that with DOM. You'll need to get action manager descriptors from your layer and parse it

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy thanks for the reply, but I don't understand what you mean. I'm new in the js, html scene but where exactly am I making use of DOM here. Also what do you mean by action manager. Could you please provide atleast a link to some sort of documentation?

Comment: `app.activeDocument.activeLayer` is a Photoshop DOM and it misses a lot of information. There's a second deeper layer of Photoshop code (ActionDesriptors) with _most_ of the things that happen in PS. Check the [ActionManagerHumanizer](https://github.com/jardicc/ActionManagerHumanizer) library for more info.

Comment: note that the ActionManagerHumanizer can only be used with "Photoshop CC 2015.5 and higher". Also note that Photoshop CS2 (the version I use) has no proper documentation of the Action Manager.

Comment: Well, cs2 is 15 years old now. There are a _lot_ of things that won't work in it

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery [`.css()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp) to get the CSS properties of html elements.

The below example looks for the color of "spans" but in your case just apply the same logic to your text layers your getting with  `var layers = collectAllLayers(doc);`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>



    
<div>
    <span style="color: red">Hey, </span>
    <span style="color: green">this </span>
    <span style="color: blue">is</span>
    <span style="color: lightgreen">a </span>
    <span style="color: orange">sentence</span>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>


</body>


<script type="text/javascript">
    
    function getColors(){
        //Store colors in array
        var arr = [];
        
        //Get elements you need the color from
        var elm = document.querySelectorAll('span');

        //Loop through each element and store its color in an array (with jQuery .css())
        elm.forEach(item => {
            console.log($(item).css('color'));
            arr.push($(item).css('color'));
        });

        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = arr;
    }

getColors();
</script>
</html>
```